# For each loop on Java HashMap

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

A basic chat program I wrote has several key words that generate special actions, images, messages, etc. I store all of the key words and special functions in a HashMap. Key words are the keys and functions are the values. I want to compare user input to the keys with some type of loop. I have tried everything I can think of and nothing works. This is what I can figure out:

```
myHashMap = <File Input>
for(String currentKey : <List of HashMap Keys>){
    if(user.getInput().equalsIgnoreCase(currentKey)){
        //Do related Value action
    }
}
...
```

I would appreciate any help. Forgive me if I overlooked a similar question or if the answer is obvious.

Comment: How are you storing a function in a Hashmap? Do you mean a listener?

Comment: You can get a list of keys with `myHashMap.keySet()` if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently iterate over each entry in a 'Map'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, you can write:

```
for(String currentKey : myHashMap.keySet()){
```

but this isn't really the best way to use a hash-map.

A better approach is to populate `myHashMap` with all-lowercase keys, and then write:

```
theFunction = myHashMap.get(user.getInput().toLowerCase());
```

to retrieve the function (or `null` if the user-input does not appear in the map).

Comment: I keep coming back to this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 70):

If you need access to both key and value then this is the most efficient way

```
    for(Entry<String, String> e : m.entrySet()) {
        String key = e.getKey();
        String value = e.getValue();
    }
```

Comment: If you want immutable access to the `Entry`, make `e` `final`.

Answer (score 12):

Only in Java 8 & above

```
map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("Key: " + k + "Value: " + v));
```

Answer (score 1):

A better pattern here might be:

```
Value val = hashMap.get(user.getInput());
if (val != null) {
    doVal();
}
else {
    // handle normal, non-keyword/specfial function
}
```

which takes advantage of the fact that HashMap returns `null` if the key isn't contained in the Map.